# Multidimensional array alter key value pair

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have the following data array -

```
      0         1
#1   "Fname"  "Lname"
#2   "Tom"    "Shaw"
#3   "Marc"   "Hob"
#4   "Sim"    "Pow"
```

And I want to change it to a key value pair set where "Fname" will be the key for "Tom", "Mark" & "Sim" and "Lname" will be the key for "Shaw", "Hob" & "Pow.

If I loop through this array -

```
foreach ($data as $key=>$value) {
    echo $key.'<br>';
    foreach ($value as $v) {
        echo $v.'<br>';
    }
}
```

I get the following output -

```
0
Fname
Lname
1
Tom
Shaw
2
Marc
Hob
3
Sim
Pow
```

Which suggests that 'Fname, Lname', 'Tom, Shaw'.. etc. is another set of array,
which I simply want as key value pair.

I am new to php programming and will really appreciate help from programming ninjas to solve this problem.

Thank you.

Comment: What structure? Do you want `fname=>array(tom,marc)` or `0=>array(fname=>tom,lname=>shaw)`

Comment: The desired structure is 0=>array(fname=>tom,lname=>shaw)

This array will have other many other columns after Fname & LName, like email, ph., add, etc.  so I need a dynamic method to set array value pair for any n number of columns.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
$keys = array_shift($data);
$result = array_map(function($v) use ($keys) { return array_combine($keys, $v); }, $data);
```

But might be simpler with a loop:

```
$keys = array_shift($data);
foreach($data as $vals) {
    $result[] = array_combine($keys, $vals);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you want:

```
$new_array = array();

foreach ($data as $value) 
{
  $new_array[] = array('Fname' => $value[0], 'Lname' => $value[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think @Marcovecchio was on the right track, but not quite spot on. Building on his code, you could use:

```
<?php

// create your new array
$new_array = array();

// pull 'Fname' and 'Lname' off original array, and set them as $col
$col = array_shift($data);

// iterate through original array, which now contains just names
foreach ($data as $value) {

    // set $col values as keys for each element
    $new_array[] = array($col[0] => $value[0], $col[1] => $value[1]);
}

// output what we just made
print_r($new_array);

?>
```

Output:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [Fname] => Tom 
        [Lname] => Shaw 
    ) 
    [1] => Array ( 
        [Fname] => Marc 
        [Lname] => Hob 
    ) 
    [2] => Array ( [
        Fname] => Sim 
        [Lname] => Pow 
    ) 
)
```

Note: This assumes that the number of columns will always be 2.

Comment: Thank you for your response. This solution seems close but This array will have other many other columns after Fname & LName, like email, ph., add, etc. so I need a dynamic method to set array value pair for any n number of columns.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
$arr = array(array('Fname','Lname'), array('Tom','Shaw'), array('Marc','Hob'), array('Sim','Pow'));

$out = array();

foreach($arr[0] as $cols){
        $out[$cols] = array();
}

foreach($arr as $key => $row){
    $i = '0';
    if($key != '0'){
        foreach($out as $out_key=>$out_row){
            $out[$out_key][] = $row[$i];
            $i++;
        }
    }
}

print_R($out);
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Array (
    [Fname] => Array
        (
            [0] => Tom
            [1] => Marc
            [2] => Sim
        )

    [Lname] => Array
        (
            [0] => Shaw
            [1] => Hob
            [2] => Pow
        )

)
```